# Issue in dynamic form list when using useState in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

here is my [code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-2djy5g-cn9wjn?file=index.js).

The code:

```
    const [isRent, setIsRent] = useState(null);

      const residentialSituation = [
        { value: 'rent', label: 'I rent' },
        { value: 'owned', label: 'I owned' },
      ];

    <Form>
      <Form.List name="users">
        {(fields, { add }) => {
          return (
            <>
              <Button
                type="dashed"
                onClick={() => {
                  add();
                }}
                block
              >
                Add
              </Button>
              {fields.map((field, i) => (
                <Collapse key={i} accordion>
                  <Panel header={i}>
                    <Form.Item
                      name={[field.name, 'residentialSituation']}
                      fieldKey={[field.fieldKey, 'residentialSituation']}
                    >
                      <Select
                        autoComplete="new-password"
                        showSearch={true}
                        onChange={(value) => setIsRent(value)}
                      >
                        {residentialSituation.map((el) => (
                          <Select.Option value={el.value} key={el.value}>
                            {el.label}
                          </Select.Option>
                        ))}
                      </Select>
                    </Form.Item>

                    {isRent === 'rent' && (
                      <Form.Item
                        label="price"
                        name={[field.name, 'rent']}
                        fieldKey={[field.fieldKey, 'rent']}
                      >
                        <Input />
                      </Form.Item>
                    )}
                  </Panel>
                </Collapse>
              ))}
            </>
          );
        }}
      </Form.List>
    </Form>
```

When I am clicking on `add` button new collapse was successfully adding.

Now I have two options in my `select` component choose `I rent` or `I owned`. When I am choosing `I rent` I am setting that value in useState and checking if `isRent === 'rent'` then render second input.

The problem is when I am adding a second collapse the `select` component is also reading from the state.

How can I set the different states for the different collapses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I updated your [code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-2djy5g-1kof6q?file=index.js).

So you need to do following.

1. Your useState state should be an object.

```
    const [inputState, setInputState] = useState({});
```

2. In select you should pass 2 arguments, select value and id.

```
    <Select onChange={(value) => handleChange(value, i)}>
       ...
    </Select>
```

3. In `handleChange` function do following. For every id set appropriate value.

```
    const handleChange = (e, i) => {
        setinputState({
          ...inputState,
          [i]: e,
        });
      };
```

4. With following condition check and render your component

```
    {inputState[i] === 'rent' && (<Form.Item> ... </Form.Item>}
```